# Cloud Build docker image unable to write files locally - fail to open file... permission denied

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Using Service Account credentials, I am successful at running Cloud Build to spin up gsutil, move files from gs into the instance, then copy them back out.  All is good.

One of the Cloud Build steps successfully loads a docker image from outside source, it loads fine and reports its own help info successfully.  But when run, it fails with the error message:
"fail to open file "..intermediary_work_product_file." permission denied.

For the app I'm running in this step, this error is typically produced when the file cannot be written to its default location.  I've set dir = "/workspace" to confirm the default.

So how do I grant read/write permissions to the app running inside a Cloud Build step to write its own intermediary work product to the local folders?   The Cloud Build itself is running fine using Service Account credentials.  Have tried adding more permissions including with Storage, Cloud Run, Compute Engine, App Engine admin roles.  But the same error.

I assume that the credentials used to create the instance are passed to the run time.  Have dug deep into the GCP CloudBuild documentation and examples, but found no answers.

There must be something fundamental I'm overlooking.

Comment: Hi @GGAnderson I would recommend you to take a look at the permission that the Cloud Build Service Account has - information available [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-build-service-account) - and then, try to provide the same permissions to the account used by your application as indicated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-project-members). This way, you should have both places with the same permissions.

Comment: Which container do you use in this failing step? Does it fail with any container? Does your GIT repository contain special autorisation on this file? (Was this file committed with 400 permission for example?

Comment: The cloudbuild.yaml has 4 steps, each loading and running from a different container.   The log shows that the image is installing fine, the app starts as it should, but halts with a permission error when trying to read an intermediary file it created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem; the snippet I was looking for in my cloudbuild manifest was:

```
  - id: perms
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    entrypoint: "chmod"
    args: ["-v", "-R", "a+rw", "."]
    dir: "path/to/some/dir"
```

Comment: This is a better answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This problem was resolved by changing the Dockerfile USER as suggested by [@PRAJINPRAKASH](https://github.com/PRAJINPRAKASH) in this helpful answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218160/4882696

Tried to solve this by systematically testing GCP services and role permissions.  All Service Account credentials tested were able to create container instances, and run gcloud or gutil fine.  However, the custom apps created containers but failed when doing local write even to the default shared /workspace.

When using GCP Cloud Build, local read/write permissions do not "pass through" from the default service account to the runtime instance.  The documentation is not clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem while building my react app with Cloud Build, i wasn't able to install `node-sass` globally...

So i tried to `chown` recursively the `/usr` directory to nobody:nogroup, and it worked. I have no idea if there is another better solution to this, but, the important thing, it fixed my issue.